# Unnecessary 'else' after 'return'. (No-else-return)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am using es-lint to clean up the errors in my code. I have come across this error:

> Unnecessary 'else' after 'return'. (No-else-return)

```
} else {
```

I have always used else statements after a return. Is there something I may be overlooking?

```
if (cctot <= 3 && cctot > 0) {
    alert('Credit under $3.00 not allowed');
    return Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER; // important to return 0 so we can check for these conditions for validation
} else {
    cctot *= -1;
}
return precise(cctot);
```

Comment: Please post complete snippet, only then we will he able to help

Comment: If the `return` is executed, the function exits. Using an `else` there is redundant and misleading.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-else-return

Comment: @Pointy _Using an else there is redundant and misleading._ Huh? Guiding developers through your conditional logic by providing all branches is misleading? The less code, the better? I don't think so!

Comment: @ftor well me and es-lint apparently disagree!

Comment: @pointy There are good abstractions for `if` conditions: Higher order functions, tagged unions. If your code is based on `Boolean` bits, at least be honest and show all cases. Abstracting from `else` branches because they are technically unnecessary is a false understanding of cleverness. I don't care about es-lint. However, disagreeing with you is a new experience for me. So, no offense!

Comment: Let's not forget that ESLint is only there to help us enforce our opinionated conventions. It's not up to ESLint to help the coder determine the difference between right and wrong or "best practices" in the JavaScript community, its merely a tool to help teams and individuals establish their own conventions. In this case, whoever setup the ESLint configurations decided that` else-returns` are redundant, but that doesn't mean they are wrong if someone prefers to use them.

Comment: See also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780384/should-if-statement-always-have-an-else-clause and over there on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375297/if-and-else-or-if-and-return

Answer (score 70, accepted):

What that is basically saying is that the else part of the if statement is unnecessary if there is a `return` in the `if` part.
Something like this is what it expects:

```
if (cctot <= 3 && cctot > 0) {
      alert('Credit under $3.00 not allowed');
      return Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER; // important to return 0 so we can check for these conditions for validation
}
cctot *= -1;
```

In general, this:

```
if (condition) {
  return something;
} else {
  // do another thing
}

return anotherThing;
```

is similar to:

```
if (condition) {
  return something;
}

// do another thing
return anotherThing;
```

After the `if` with a `return` statement, there is no need for the `else` part as the code below the `if` will only run when the condition stated is not fulfilled.

Comment: This is totally the way to go.

Comment: That version **has** the `else`. What does the version with the "parsing error" look like?

Comment: @DavidBrierton: You may want to submit that code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com since there's a good bit of redundancy that can be eliminated.

Comment: @DavidBrierton It doesn't even make sense to use an `else` there. Apparently you want to flip the sign of the credit value right before you return it at the end of the function. This has nothing to do with the `if` that that `else` is attached to.

Comment: @DavidBrierton If you remove an `else {` you need to remove the closing brace at the end of the block. Is that not obvious?

Comment: Would it be better if I be explicit and add the additional 2 or 3 lines for `else`, or remove it all together?

Comment: @StackGeek you should remove it altogether if you have a `return` in the `if { }` block otherwise add it.

Comment: 0

How is this wrong by having a return on if when it was intended?
```
if (something === true) {
  return doSomething();
} else if (anotherThing === true) {
  return doSomethingElse();
} # add more else conditions as necessary 

// if neither is true
doDefaultThing();
```

why would it be wrong to force termination of the function by returning on each condition? The use case for example is that we want to prevent what is a default implementation and force termination when certain conditions are met.

Comment: @AdonisLeeVillamor, in your use case you can simply just do `if (something === true) return doSomething()` `if (anotherThing === true) return doAnotherThing();` and so on without need to wrap it in else block

Comment: what if there are multiple if-else conditions?

Comment: @DerekJin same rule will apply assuming all the blocks use `return`

Answer (score 33):

It's a code style preference. You don't need the `else` and instead can put the `else` code directly below the `if`. This is because if the `if` succeeds, that's the end of the function, so the `else` code will never be reached anyway.

So this:

```
if (condition) {
  return foo;
} else {
  // do bar
}

return baz
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if (condition) {
  return foo;
}

// do bar

return baz
```

This style seems to vary in different programming communities. Go developers will nearly always omit the `else`, while I've seen more JS devs include it.

While I prefer to leave off the `else`, it is again purely a matter of preference. Don't let it worry you too much. People may get dogmatic about this kind of thing, but it's really not that important.

Comment: I think @llama's advice is spot on, especially when then the if block is more than a few lines. Then the else condition can really help with clarity.

Comment: If you disassemble the resulting code with the 'else' you'll see a redundant 'jmp' instruction as well.

Answer (score 11):

While the rule correctly points out that the `else` block is unnecessary, and it is a style preference, I would add additional considerations for **readability** and most importantly **scanability**.

For the developer writing this code, and to the machine interpreting it, it may be a style point and that's it. But for the developer who needs to fix a bug, enhance a feature, do a code review, etc. the ability to quickly scan through the code and see the `else` blocks helps to identify branches of logic.

In a few lines of isolated code it is easy to see the intent, but among hundreds of lines of code having `if` `else` blocks can serve as useful identifiers, much like other common visual practices like indentation, line breaks, and naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement stops/terminates the current function. It's just saying that  there's no need for 'else' since the execution of the function already stopped and if the 'if' condition doesn't succeed, it will still run any code underneath it.

As for best practice, I won't say it's a big of a deal always but with the code in your example, I won't use the else clause because it's simply not needed. I think it's good to understand what's happening under the hood and the reason behind best practices and not just following them.

Comment: Good code transparently reflects developer's intention and is meant to read by engineers first, not by machines. It's obviously bad to skip `else` just "because it's not needed" (by engine). If you don't skip "else" when you talk about what your code does it's already a good reason not to remove "else" from the code.