# How to create a function in C that prompts the user for positive integers only and call it in the main function?

Tags: c, cs50

This is my code. I failed to use the break keyword after the printf function in order to break out of the loop. When I enter a negative number or zero, it doesn't prompt me again to re-enter.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int get_positive_int(void);

int main (void)
{
    get_positive_int();
}


int get_positive_int(void)
{   
  int i;
  i = get_int("Integer: ");

  while (true)
  {
    if (i<1)
    {
       return i;
    }
    else
    {
       printf("%i", i);  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You’ve wrote the code to exit the function when the number is less than one. If you want it to ask again you’ll have to tell it to do that.

Comment: Hint: your `while` is misplaced. Basically this is the algorithm you need: 1. get integer. 2. if it's positive, return it. 3. if it's negative go to step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm in the function `get_positive_int()` is wrong:

1. You need to place `i = get_int("Integer: ");` inside of the `while` loop.
2. Your `if` condition:

```
if (i < 1)
```

is wrong as that would return `i` if `i` is a negative integer or `0`. If you want to return `i` when `i` is a positive integer or `0` you should use `if(i >= 0)`.

3. Note that you can also place:

```
if (i == INT_MAX)
{
   // optional error handling.
   return INT_MAX;
}
```

after the call to maintain the occurrence of a read error. But if you want to only return `INT_MAX` then, you do not need to do so and can omit it since this would fit to the conditional statement ``if(i >= 0)` and its body.

---

The code is then:

```
int get_positive_int(void)
{   
  int i;

  while (true)
  {
    i = get_int("Integer: ");

    if (i == INT_MAX)
    {
        // optional error handling.
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    else if (i >= 0)
    {
       return i;
    }

    printf("%i", i);  
  }
}
```

Side note: If you don´t want to count `0` as positive integer, you need to have `i >= 1` as the condition of the `if` statement.

---

As you said in the comments you only want to continue if `i` is a positive integer and exit if `i` is a negative characters or `0`:

```
void get_positive_int(void)
{   
  int i;

  while (true)
  {
    i = get_int("Integer: ");

    if (i < 1)
    {
       return;
    }

    printf("%i\n", i);  
  }
}
```

Note that in this case, the return type of `get_positive_int` shall be `void` instead of `int` and it should omit to return `i` as it is not necessary to return any value from the function.

Comment: What is the need for the `if (i == INT_MAX)` block?  Looks discardable.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If `get_int()` can´t read, it returns `INT_MAX`. It´s a cs50-thing.

Comment: Interesting.  [`get_int()`](http://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.c) also returns `INT_MAX` when the value read is `INT_MAX`.  Looks like `get_int()` does not provide for reading a valid `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So, now It should be all fixed. I often times don´t mind/overlook things when I have an idea about and the focus on another. Bad attribute of mine.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I´ve forget: Thank you for your hints.

Comment: [Unnecessary 'else' after 'return'. (No-else-return)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46875442/2410359) applies here for your consideration.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right. I changed that, too, but kept the `else if` because both are related.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Thank you so much! It actually not what I wanted, but you've just taught me a new way to deal with while loop.

My problem was fixed after placing the i = get_int(".......") in the while loop...
I only needed to keep getting prompt when I enter positive integers, but exit when I enter a zero or negative integer.

Thanks again for your time :).

Comment: @tareq91z Is the added example an approach to what you want?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio That's exactly what I want. You've just given me more approach to handle this problem! Thanks a lot :).