# Is there a benefit/downside to return in an else statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, return

Version 1:

```
int abc(...)
{
    if(a || b || c))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Version 2:

```
int abc(...)
{
    if(a || b || c))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any difference? 
Which code is the proper one?

Comment: There is no difference, I prefer `return (a || b || c);`

Comment: No difference at all.

Comment: The difference is only in which version matches the coding styles/habits in your environment. Easily in one company any of them can be "wrong".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unnecessary 'else' after 'return'. (No-else-return)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875442/unnecessary-else-after-return-no-else-return) Different language, agreed, but the concept is the same.

Comment: In this case it makes no difference, as the others have already said. However i would like to add that, in a more complicated function, your "version 2" style can potentially make it hard to follow the control-flow (for example when there are `return` statements buried deep in some nested `if` clauses). In other words: in some cases it can help readability to have all return statements at the same "level" (or have just one single return statement instead of multiple ones)

Comment: See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157407/best-practice-on-if-return and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375297/if-and-else-or-if-and-return

Comment: The closing of this question is discussed at Stack Overflow Meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397791/is-it-appropriate-to-close-a-question-as-duplicate-of-another-language-one). Feel free to participate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "*Is there any difference?*"

No.

> "*Which code is the proper one?*"

None. They are equivalent. Note if the `else` isn´t explicitly needed for the context, omit it since it is redundant:

[Unnecessary 'else' after 'return'. (No-else-return)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875442/unnecessary-else-after-return-no-else-return)

Note: The linked question is for Javascript, but it shares the same concern of yours.

---

Furthermore, your code could be simplified:

```
int abc (...)
{
    return (a || b || c);
}
```

If the condition is true `1`, else `0` is returned.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference since, upon returning `1`, no further code in the function is executed anyway, and *one* of the paths must be chosen.

I prefer the latter since it involves less typing but that's really just a matter of preference.

Of course, there are other options as well such as the simpler:

```
return a || b || c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both code variants are the same and will generate same assembly instructions.
But more elegant way is:

```
int abc(...)
{
    return (a || b || c);
}
```